# Why can't get vid and pid in device manager?

Tags: usb, device-manager

Plug in my usb and check in device manager,select `General UDisk USB Device`:

[image]

I can't get the usb's vid and pid value.

Enter into cmd with administrator permission:

```
wmic path CIM_LogicalDevice where "Description like 'USB%'" get /value


Availability=
Caption=USB Mass Storage Device
ClassCode=
ConfigManagerErrorCode=0
ConfigManagerUserConfig=FALSE
CreationClassName=Win32_USBHub
CurrentAlternateSettings=
CurrentConfigValue=
Description=USB Mass Storage Device
DeviceID=USB\VID_ABCD&amp;PID_1234\5&amp;186144F5&amp;0&amp;4
ErrorCleared=
ErrorDescription=
GangSwitched=
InstallDate=
LastErrorCode=
Name=USB Mass Storage Device
NumberOfConfigs=
NumberOfPorts=
PNPDeviceID=USB\VID_ABCD&amp;PID_1234\5&amp;186144F5&amp;0&amp;4
PowerManagementCapabilities=
PowerManagementSupported=
ProtocolCode=
Status=OK
StatusInfo=
SubclassCode=
SystemCreationClassName=Win32_ComputerSystem
SystemName=DESKTOP-IM4RDOM
USBVersion=
```

I get the vid value--ABCD and pid value--1234.Why can't get it in device manager?In which situation can't get vid and pid value in device manager?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you’re not looking at the USB device. You’re looking at a disk device. This is evident from the fact that you are not looking at a device captioned “USB Mass Storage Device”, which is what you got with `wmic`.

Switch your Device Manager to “Devices by connection” when you have the device you are interested in selected. It will remain selected and you will see its parent devices.

[image: Device Manager by connection]

Comment: Just select the universal serial bus controller.